# Are full backups & recoveries not possible?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

While it appears that Salesforce supports backups of data & configs, it also appears that a [complete backup is not possible](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm). Have I misunderstood the meaning of this page?

For example, does this mean:

- Using Salesforce's Metadata API, that the [components referenced above](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm) can not be retrieved or
  deployed with it - but
  there are other ways to download all data & configs outside of Salesforce's Metadata API.
- The components referenced above are ONLY accessible manually regardless method unless
  HTTP is used as a method of documenting and "auto-manually" deploying
  these components' settings; by "auto-manually" I mean that a bot is
  scripted to access the related points of configuration to configure
  the platform as if they were a human.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, blunders. Those components cannot be deployed at all and must be configured through the UI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those components cannot be deployed at all and must be configured through the UI. You probably could use something like Selenium to mimic the steps, if needed.

Comment: Thanks, just for clarity, your answer states that "those components cannot be deployed", but is also correct to say that there is also no way to systematically document modifications to those components other than the HTTP as "an API" method, correct?

Comment: Correct; to document recreating them would require writing down every option from every page to setup the features in your link.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to document changes (only those available to the metadata api) you can look at using Git backups. you can then schedule git backups and review any changes that were made.  If you have a tool like [Copado Deployer](http://www.copa.do) (appexchange app that can be used free) you can schedule these back ups. Then you can configure a workflow rule to let you know when changes were made.

Git repositories from bitbucket.org are free and private. I'd recommend using them.

Here's a link to the app: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3dgGEAR